# Работа с классами,объекты

Tags: c++, классы, объекты

```
Student* student1 = new Student("Vince", "Vaughn", "7-th Avenue", "New York", "783-945-90-28", 49);
Student* student2 = new Student("Vince", "Mcmahon", "Beverly Hills", "Los Angeles", "874-940-42-12", 47);
Student* student3 = new Student("Stone Cold", "Steve Austin", "Dallas", "Texas", "385-421-47-95", 34);

Course Intermediate_Cpp[3];
Intermediate_Cpp[3] = {};
```

Каким образом возможно передать массиву `Intermediate_Cpp[3]` класса `Course{};` ,который в свою очередь является объектом этого класса,объекты `student1`, `student2`, `student3` другого класса `Student{};`?

Comment: Я правильно вас понимаю - в массив одного типа вы хотите поместить объекты другого типа? Грубо говоря, разместить в массиве из трех символов три числа `double`?

Comment: Не совсем так,в массив Intermediate_Cpp[3],мне необходимо поместить объекты student1,student2,student3.Соответственно все значения которые принимают эти объекты в скобках.

Comment: Если класс  Course  может конструироваться с обьектом Student тогда другое дело. Но, кажется, вы просто что то путаете_  ntermediate_Cpp[3] содержит(может содержать) три экземпляра класса   Course, а не является обьектом этого класса

Comment: Тогда вообще ничего не понимаю... Есть массив из трех элементов типа `Course`. **КУДА** вы хотите поместить эти объекты **совершенно другого типа**? Я просто заменил `Course` на `char`, `Student` на `double` и задал ваш же вопрос - вы говорите, что нет, все не так. А как?

Comment: что у вас за задание?

Comment: Мне необходимо записать в массив ,который принадлежит другому классу,выше указанные объекты student1,student2,student3

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в класс Course добавить, например, поле `std::list<Student *>` и вытащить наружу методы `void add(Student *)` и `remove(Student *)`, которые будут оперировать списком.

В итоге добавление будет выглядеть как то так:

```
Student* student1 = new Student("Vince", "Vaughn", "7-th Avenue", "New York", "783-945-90-28", 49);
Student* student2 = new Student("Vince", "Mcmahon", "Beverly Hills", "Los Angeles", "874-940-42-12", 47);
Student* student3 = new Student("Stone Cold", "Steve Austin", "Dallas", "Texas", "385-421-47-95", 34);

Course *Intermediate_Cpp;
Intermediate_Cpp->add(student1);
Intermediate_Cpp->add(student2);
Intermediate_Cpp->add(student3);
```